# SQL Query find users with only one product type

Tags: sql, count, having

I solemnly swear I did my best to find an existing question, may I'm not sure how to phrase it correctly.

I would like to return records for users that have quota for only one product type.

```
| user_id | product |
|       1 |     A   |
|       1 |     B   | 
|       1 |     C   | 
|       2 |     B   | 
|       3 |     B   | 
|       3 |     C   | 
|       3 |     D   |
```

In the example above I'd like a query that only returns users who carry quota for only one product type - doesn't really matter which product at this point.

I tried using `select user_id, product from table group by 1,2 having count(user) < 2` but this does not work, nor does `select user_id, product from table group by 1,2 having count(*) < 2`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should try `group by user_id having count(distinct product) = 1`

Comment: "I solemnly swear I did my best...".  So have you tried your best to create your own query????

Answer (score 2):

Your `having` clause is good; the issue's with your `group by`.  Try this:

```
select user_id
, count(distinct product) NumberOfProducts 
from table 
group by user_id
having count(distinct product) = 1
```

Or you could do this; which is closer to your original:

```
select user_id
from table 
group by user_id 
having count(*) < 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working. Is there a way to display the product name in the results?

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause can't take ordinal arguments (like, e.g., the `order by` clause can). When grouping by a value like `1`, you're in fact grouping by the literal value `1`, which would just be the same for any row in the table, and thus will group **all** the rows in the table to one group. Since there are more than one product in the entire table, no rows will be returned.

Instead, you should group by the `user_id`:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the product, then do:

```
select user_id, max(product) as product
from table
group by user_id
having min(product) = max(product);
```

The `having` clause could also be:

```
having count(distinct product) = 1
```

Comment: Brilliant. Both of these work beautifully. Thank you so much!